# Weird font behavior on the NSTextField

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nstextfield

I added programmatically NSTextField to my NSView:

```
NSTextField *projectLabel = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[projectLabel setStringValue:@"projectName"];
[projectLabel setBezeled:NO];
[projectLabel setDrawsBackground:NO];
[projectLabel setEditable:NO];
[projectLabel setSelectable:NO];

[projectLabel setFont:[NSFont controlContentFontOfSize:13]];
projectLabel.autoresizingMask = NSViewMaxXMargin | NSViewMinYMargin; 

[self addSubview:projectLabel];
[self setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];
```

This field was added correctly, but when I change size of view (or even move window to second display), font on field changes very weird (see attached image).

on start [image: before]
after change of the size [image: after]
I do not know what I did wrong

Comment: Not that this will help, but you should pass 0.0 for the size to get the control content font at the default size.

Comment: More relevantly: The font isn't changing at all. The text field is double-striking the text: drawing the text multiple times, each on top of the ones before.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I drew this label on drawRect every time, when the size changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I drew this label on drawRect every time, when the size changes.

So, you're manually telling the field to display in its parent view's `drawRect:`?

Don't do that. It's a subview, so it'll get told to draw in its turn anyway. Just let that happen.

Comment: Theoretically I know about this. But sometimes I do stupid mistakes :)
Thanks for your sugestions.

Comment: @TomaszWojtkowiak i also facing same issue can share me how to solve this?

Comment: @SawanCool - the solution is in Peter Hosey's answer. I just moved creation of NSTextField out from drawRect: